# Supress standard output in vim-latex-suite

Tags: vim, zathura

I use `Vim Latex-Suite` together with the PDF reader `Zathura`. In the last versions of Zathura they decided to output the following warning:

```
"warning: Failed to loads bookmarks"
```

whenever a document has no bookmarks defined (which is 99% of the time in my case).

The problem is that this warning goes to the standard output and for some reason when I call zathura from within vim, vim shows the warning over my buffer (I have to press Control+L to redraw the buffer).

Here is an example. Suppose I have this file:

http://diaz-caro.web.unq.edu.ar/inicial.png

After I call Zathura with `<Leader>lv`, Zathura opens and I get this:

http://diaz-caro.web.unq.edu.ar/final.png

My workaround was to make an script which calls zathura sending the standard and error output to /dev/null

```
zathura "$@" 2>/dev/null
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this problem? Why would vim output the warning in my buffer instead of hiding it or outputting it in another buffer as it does with LaTeX errors?

Comment: Any success with such issue?

Comment: No :( I continue with the workaround mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
zathura -l error file.pdf
```

to turn off the warning message. But it is similar to what you have, :).